# Git push reminder/helper?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Sometimes I need (in order to make my development faster) harcode some stuff in my code. That can be credentials, or maybe just a hack to allow me to test certain feature. For many reasons, I never want to push this code to the main codebase or even the development branch. For some time I've been using the 'git-assume-unchaged' command but after merges, rebases, etc that can get mixed up and you might be pushing something you don't want. Is there a cool clean way to achieve this? maybe some command that warns me that I have to remember to checkout some file before pushing or something like that? any ideas?

Comment: Why to put this kind of configuration file in Git?

They should be in .gitignore and never committed.

Alternative:
You can build a "template" file that contains the common things that you want to permanently commit, but you want to have concrete env configurations in files that git is unaware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases (like credentials) I would suggest thinking about ways in which you can avoid having to put those - even temporarily - into source-controlled files. (This might end up helping you in other ways as well.)  But there may just be cases where temporary code is the most straightforward workflow for you, so ...

One solution would be to use a `pre-commit` hook.  You could mark your temporary code with a comment (something like `// xxxTEMPxxx` in C-like languages maybe) and then reject any commit that finds your marker in the diff.  See the example in `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample`.

You can then keep your change in place as you work, committing or doing whatever, but if you `git add` the change then you'll be reminded that it's there and can unstage it.  (If you're working on other code in the same file, you can use `git add -p` to selectively stage the changes you intend to commit while keeping your temp code out.)

Of course your temp changes still exist as untracked changes, which can get in the way of some operations; but in that case you can stash them. It's got to be better than trying to play with `assume-unchanged` at least.

Comment: I use a similar method to this, except I check for the tmp-marker in `pre-push` hook (committing in my own repo is okay, but I shouldn't push the tmp code to the remote).

Also I defined a vim macro to insert the tmp-marker. That way, I can be sure that I never misspell the tmp-marker, causing the `pre-push` hook to miss it.

Comment: @Alderath - good point about avoiding mis-spelling. Which hook to use is a matter of preference I guess, but I prefer to catch it before it's in *any* repo, so that I don't end up having to split commits and/or rebase good changes away from bad ones after the fact.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger the 'pre-commit hook' was EXACTLY what I was looking for, a simple script to check a given tag! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but it helped me solve my problem.

I ended up creating a pre-commit hook that looks for a string in committed files.

So when have to hard code a value that should not go to the repository, I insert a comment like this:

`// GIT_BLOCK`

I get a warning and a list of the files.

```
#!/bin/sh
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        against=HEAD
else
        # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
        against=$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
fi

exec 1>&2

if git diff --cached --name-only $against | xargs grep --color "GIT_BLOCK"
then
  echo Commit would modify one or more files that must not change.
  exit 1
else
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want see the files that you have modified you can use `git gui`. With this you can choose the modified files to push.